# How to change the url of WebView and timed refresh the page by connecting to the back-end server

Tags: android, webview

I want to achieve this function:

There is a background service:

1) When the  network is off-line, the background services continue to detect, if the resumption of the network, refresh webView, restore display.

2) When the network is OK, the background services will continue to detect, if the background server is given a new url, then refresh the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a Broadcast Receiver along with AlarmManager and PendingIntent. Set repeating of the Alarm for your desired duration, and fire the pending Intent at that duration.

```
public void scheduleAlarmForURLAutoUpdate() {
        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;// current time + 24 Hrs
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent intentAlarm  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, intentAlarm);// 24 Hrs
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for 24 Hrs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

AlarmReceiver Class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateURL(context);//Method to update the URL from the server and then refresh your WebView activity


}
```

Comment: I'm really grateful  for your answer.But I still can't resolve this question.If I get the new URL from the server, how  could I refresh my webView?Which method  could I use?   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AutoUpdateService.class);
    context.startService(i);
}
```

}